# How to use int 13 with AH=03h interrupt in assembly to fill a sector with zeroes?

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt, bios

So far i have this:

```
mov ah,02h
mov cl,11001100001111011101000b ;6,692,584 in dec
mov dl,0
int 13
```

Comment: That doesn't look like any assembly language I've ever seen.  Can you describe your system and environment?

Comment: It would be a bootable script sorry im new to assembly, i'll edit the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see the following issues with your code:

- `AH` should be 3 rather than 2 (2 is for reading).
- `CL` is only eight bits so is unlikely to be holding that big honkin' value.
- You need to set `AH`, `AL`, `CH`, `CL`, `DH`, `DL` and `ES:BX` as per the following table:

---

```
AH     03h
AL     Number of sectors to write
CH     Track number
CL     Sector number
DH     Head number
DL     Drive number
ES:BX  Buffer to write
```

And, if you ever need information on interrupts, you should google for "Ralf Brown". This guy created and maintained the definitive interrupt list back in the days before we were insulated from such things. See, for example, [the indexed HTML version](http://ctyme.com/rbrown.htm).

Your specific needs can be met from [the `Int 13/AH=03h` section](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0608.htm).

A sample, though untested and written in real mode, would be something along the following lines:

```
      mov  ax, 0301h           ; cmd 3 (write sector), 1 sector
      mov  cx, 0001h           ; track 0, sector 1
      mov  dx, 0000h           ; head 0, drive 0
      mov  es, segment buff    ; segment and offset of buffer
      mov  bx, offset buff
      int  13h                 ; make the call
      jc   errp                ; detect error
      ret

errp:                          ; process error here
      ret

buff: db   0(256)              ; buffer to write
```

Comment: Where'd you get the info for his benefit?

Comment: But cl is the sector i want to write to right? I want to write to the sector 6,692,584

Comment: Would I have to change to the 32 bit registers? Id that's possible with boot able code?

Comment: @P'sao, int 13/3 handle cylinders, sectors, heads and such. You'll need to calculate those from your sector number or find another int to do that for you.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, I've updated the answer to show the source. "Ralf Brown" is one of those strings nearly hard-wired into my brain from long ago :-)

Comment: @P'sao, 32-bit registers won't help, the BIOS comes up in real mode. Unless your BIOS provides extensions, you'll have to live with what's available.

Comment: Thanks, so to write more than one sector all you would have to do is change the ax value? also if you were to write more than one value what would the cx value be? ex: number of sectors to write are "3" and the sectors to write are: "3,8,10"?

Comment: @P'sao, if the sectors you want to write are not contiguous, you need to call int13 for each, setting `al` to 1 in all cases. If you wanted to write four (contiguous) sectors starting with track 2, sector 3, you would set `ax` to `0304` and `cx` to `0203`.

Comment: How would you find what track your sector is on?

Comment: I got the track number 125,047 from the sector number 7877976 by dividing the sector number by 63... is that the way to do it.